# Does it make sense that the expectation of a random variable depends on the mapping?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

For example

The random process defined by "color observed in a pixel"
have the following outcomes:

$G, B, R$

And we have a discrete random variable $X_1$, which can create a mapping between each value and a number, por example

$G \rightarrow 0$, $P(X_1 = 0) = 0.66 $

$B \rightarrow 1$, $P(X_1 = 1) = 0.17 $

$R \rightarrow 2$, $P(X_1 = 2) = 0.17$

finally we are interested in the expectation:
 $E_1[X] = 0*0.66 + 1*0.17 + 2*0.17 = 0.51 $

But we could make an alternative mapping, with an alternative random variable $X_2$

$G \rightarrow 2$, $P(X_2 = 2) = 0.66 $

$B \rightarrow 1$, $P(X_2 = 1) = 0.17$

$R \rightarrow 0$, $P(X_2 = 0) = 0.17$

so $E_2[X] = 2*0.66 + 1*0.17 + 0*0.17 = 1.49 $

The probabilities are the same, we only have changed the defining of the mapping. Its intuitive for me that the mapping shouldn't have importance in the results, because its only a way to describe the events in a numeric form.

So, how we can interpret the different between the expectancy results?

Comment: As a general proposition, when you change how you describe a phenomenon, your descriptions of many aspects of that phenomenon change, too.  As a simple example, when you change from measuring weight in pounds to kilograms, the *number* used to represent the total weight of a collection of objects changes, too.  There's nothing mysterious about that.  What, if anything, in this question differs from that circumstance?

Comment: ok thanks, I was a little confused.